# Merging the elements of a list containing ImageCollection into a single ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine Javascript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-explorer

I am trying to merge the elements of a list that contains the ImageCollection for the month of January 2016 to 2022. I want to merge them into one ImageCollection containing all the images.

```js
// var roi = location of study

Map.centerObject(roi);

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'), ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING')))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select('VV');

var years = ee.List.sequence(2016, 2022);

var january = function (year) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
    var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 31);
    var filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));
    return filtered;
};


var januaryCollection = years.map(january);
print(januaryCollection.flatten());

var january2016 = ee.ImageCollection(januaryCollection.get(0));
var january2017 = ee.ImageCollection(januaryCollection.get(1));
var january2018 = ee.ImageCollection(januaryCollection.get(2));
var january2019 = ee.ImageCollection(januaryCollection.get(3));
var january2020 = ee.ImageCollection(januaryCollection.get(4));
var january2021 = ee.ImageCollection(januaryCollection.get(5));
var january2022 = ee.ImageCollection(januaryCollection.get(6));
var merged_c = january2016.merge(january2017).merge(january2018).merge(january2019).merge(january2020).merge(january2021).merge(january2022);

print('merged_c', merged_c)
```

I have manually written the code merging 2016 to 2022, but I want to use a loop that automatically does it instead of typing all these lines of extra code. I have tried to use a function to do it, but I just couldn't make it merge all of them. I plan to do it for other months too, so a loop would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky and non-intuitive unless you know that "Collections and Image are all technically 'Features'".

So, you simply turn the list into a FeatureCollection, flatten that collection of collections, and then cast back to an ImageCollection:

```
ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(januaryCollection).flatten())
```